Is there way to configure expo 'open web', so it processes react native syntax like actual android device/emulator?
While converting a React app into an expo react native app, I was using open web option  (i.e. w in the screen below) to test my changes, without deploying the app to the emulator.
At some point, when I finally did deploy the app to the emulator, it would not even start there because of various issues which not manifest themselves in the web version e.g. leftover html markup, chunks of text not wrapped into <Text> etc, so it took me quite a bit of time to find and fix those issues.
Running the app in a browser is much faster and less tedious compared to deploying it onto the emulator and running it there, so I was wondering if there's a way to configure the open web option, so it would mimic the emulator/device in terms of processing react native syntax, so (most of) the syntax errors can be caught there?
› Press s │ switch to Expo Go

› Press a │ open Android
› shift+a │ select a device or emulator
› Press w │ open web  <------- 
....

